# How to stop developer powershell from coming up when debugging?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2022

In VS2022 I have an application that I am working on and at one point I opened the project in terminal (right click project -> Open In Terminal) and it brought up developer powershell. This worked fine.  I closed the terminal window and thought that was it. It was not.

Now when I run any project/solution in debug mode, developer powershell comes up!  I close VS2022 and reopen and load a new or existing solution and when I run in debug mode, developer powershell opens up.  I do not want this to keep happening.

**How can I stop this behavior?**  I cannot find anything that will turn it off. Is this a new bug with visual studio??

**10/9/2023**
I put in a report to Microsoft on this.  The status is as follows:
[image]

**UPDATE**
April 3, 2024
When this ticket was put in VS2022 was at 17.7.4.  Now at 17.9.5 it appears to be fixed.

[image]

I tested and it does appear that the issue is resolved.  The other way to resolve this was to do a repair on the VS 2022 installation. Which one of my teammates did and it resolved it for him.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Any answer on this one ?

Comment: @kostakis To date there has been no answer from Microsoft since my last post... I did a repair on my installation for another reason and that seemed to have reset so now powershell does not come up when I debug.

Comment: @Kioxoka Indeed, repairing VS solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In VS2022 you can change the default by going to `Tools`->`Options`

In the options screen look for `Environment`->`Terminal`

Here you'll see two Profiles **Developer Powershell (Default)** and **Developer Command Prompt**

Simply select **Developer Command Prompt** and then click "Set as Default"

Comment: That does not help me... I know i can change the terminal type, the problem is that when I run my app in debug (F5) the terminal window now comes up either powershell or command prompt.  Whichever I choose.  I do NOT want this behavior to continue but I have not found a way to turn it off.  I do not want the terminal to continue to pop up as it were....